# How can can I get equidistant location on a MKPolyline?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mkmapview

I need to find equidistant locations on a MKPolyline to add annotations as shown below.

[image]

My function to get locations on MKPolyline is given below, I have the values start and end coordinates of Polyline. But the locations are slightly ,moving out of polyline as shown in the image below

[image]

My function to find location is

```
func getEquidistantPoints(from startPoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to endPoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D, numberOfPoints: Int) -> [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {

        var midPoints: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
        var newPoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0)

        let count = numberOfPoints + 1
        let latitudeModifier = (endPoint.latitude - startPoint.latitude) / Double(count)
        let longitudeModifier = (endPoint.longitude - startPoint.longitude) / Double(count)

        for i in 0..<count {
            newPoint.latitude = CLLocationDegrees(startPoint.latitude + (latitudeModifier * Double(i)))
            newPoint.longitude = CLLocationDegrees(startPoint.longitude + (longitudeModifier * Double(i)))
            midPoints.append(newPoint)
        }
        return midPoints
    }
```

In viewdidload

```
let coordinatesArray = getEquidistantPoints(from: sourceCoordinate, to: destinationCoordinate, numberOfPoints: 5)

        for coordinate in coordinatesArray {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
```

How can I solve this error in calculating locations?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the earth is round. So your "line" is not a line; it is a curve traced out on the surface of a nominal sphere. You cannot find "equidistant" points along the line using your simple-minded method. You need to use some much more serious math than you are using. This will prove to be far from trivial.